# How to make cocos2d sprite scale up and down (for a pulsating effect) every second?

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I want to have a sprite scale up and down once every second to make it seem like it is bulging and pulsating. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

As the post before contains syntax errors. To be more precise, I post working code:

```
CCSprite * sprite = ...; // create the sprite.
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:2.0];
id scaleDownAction = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:0.8 scaleY:0.8] rate:2.0];
CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleUpAction, scaleDownAction, nil];
[sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:scaleSeq]];
```

Comment: how to this animation only once?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple [CCScaleTo ..] action or if you want to create your own "effect" you could advance the CCFiniteTimeAction. I would prefer the first one :

```
CCSprite * sprite = ...; // create the sprite.
sprite.anchorPoint = ccp( 0.5, 0.5 ); center the pivot
id myAction = [CCRepeatForEver actionWithActions:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:2.0 ScaleY:2.0],[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:0.5 ScaleY:0.5], nil];
[sprite runAction:myAction];
```

use CCEase to make the animation nonlinear

```
id myAction = [CCRepeatForEver actionWithActions:[CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:2.0 ScaleY:2.0] rate:2.0],[CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:0.5 ScaleY:0.5] rate:2.0], nil];
```

this post may contain errors. but I hope you understand the way to come to the goal.